# Time machine error backup failed with error 11

Tags: macos, external-disk, time-machine

I have a western digital 2TB hard disk (wd caviar green) connected through a unitek sata hdd docking station with my macbook air (10.8.2).

When I try to backup with time machine, the backup fails with an error. I went into console.app and got following log entrys for backupd

```
2012/12/27 12:56:24.470  com.apple.backupd[289]: Starting manual backup
2012/12/27 12:56:31.635  com.apple.backupd[289]: User chose to inherit backup at path: /Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac
2012/12/27 12:56:31.890  com.apple.backupd[289]: Inherited machine directory: /Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac
2012/12/27 12:56:31.898  com.apple.backupd[289]: Backing up to: /Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb
2012/12/27 12:56:34.183  com.apple.backupd[289]: Forcing deep traversal on source: "Macintosh HD" (mount: '/' fsUUID: C30CEABF-1A09-38A3-B8C9-098B2E1AB453 eventDBUUID: 224823D7-2AD9-4A0C-938F-F30094AAFFF7)
2012/12/27 12:56:36.368  com.apple.backupd[289]: Deep event scan at path:/ reason:must scan subdirs|require scan|
2012/12/27 12:56:36.369  com.apple.backupd[289]: Finished scan
2012/12/27 1:00:21.511  com.apple.backupd[289]: Found 1069044 files (217.09 GB) needing backup
2012/12/27 1:00:22.037  com.apple.backupd[289]: 262.3 GB required (including padding), 290.27 GB available
2012/12/27 1:42:54.559  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (-50) SrcErr:NO Copying /Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Interface Builder/Plug-ins/CocoaPlugin.ibplugin/Contents/Resources/IBSliderInspector.nib to /Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-12-27-005633.inProgress/35EBED9E-CC45-4CAE-88AD-F95D34F844E8/Macintosh HD/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Interface Builder/Plug-ins/CocoaPlugin.ibplugin/Contents/Resources
2012/12/27 1:42:54.559  com.apple.backupd[289]: Stopping backup.
2012/12/27 1:42:54.559  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (-8062) SrcErr:NO Copying /Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Interface Builder/Plug-ins/CocoaPlugin.ibplugin/Contents/Resources/IBSliderInspector.nib to /Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-12-27-005633.inProgress/35EBED9E-CC45-4CAE-88AD-F95D34F844E8/Macintosh HD/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Interface Builder/Plug-ins/CocoaPlugin.ibplugin/Contents/Resources
2012/12/27 1:42:54.566  com.apple.backupd[289]: Copied 336330 files (8.41 GB) from volume Macintosh HD.
2012/12/27 1:42:54.566  com.apple.backupd[289]: Copy stage failed with error:11
2012/12/27 1:44:16.480  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (5) getxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.SnapshotState path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-10-04-042243
2012/12/27 1:45:22.007  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (5) getxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.SnapshotState path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-10-04-095142
2012/12/27 1:46:27.535  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (5) getxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.SnapshotState path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-10-04-100502
2012/12/27 2:17:14.865  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (5) getxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.SnapshotState path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-10-04-110538
2012/12/27 2:22:16.293  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (5) getxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.SnapshotState path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-10-04-120603
2012/12/27 4:22:20.314  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (5) getxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.SnapshotState path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-10-04-144009
2012/12/27 5:22:56.579  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (5) getxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.SnapshotState path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac/2012-10-04-173725
2012/12/27 5:23:45.732  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (22) setxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.HostUUID path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac size:37
2012/12/27 5:23:55.752  com.apple.backupd[289]: Backup failed with error: 11
2012/12/27 10:34:47.278  com.apple.backupd[289]: Starting automatic backup
2012/12/27 10:42:09.607  com.apple.backupd[289]: Backing up to: /Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb
2012/12/27 10:42:09.813  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (22) setxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.HostUUID path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac size:37
2012/12/27 10:42:09.814  com.apple.backupd[289]: Error: (22) setxattr for key:com.apple.backupd.HostUUID path:/Volumes/lebackup/Backups.backupdb/jerrys mac size:37
2012/12/27 10:42:19.836  com.apple.backupd[289]: Backup failed with error: 2
```

What is the reason for this backup failure and how do I resolve the problem?

Comment: I am having the same error. (Backup failed with error: 11). I am using an external non-Apple-brand USB drive attached to an apple AirPort wireless router  I wonder if there's an error between the USB drive and your computer, because I'm going to change out my USB drive and see what that does.

Comment: general time machine troubleshooting link: http://pondini.org/TM/Troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 2):

I fix my problem after trying and searching for 3 hours... the solution that work for me : Select le source disk->get info->sharing and permission and make sure sportlight, admin, and (me) are READ+WRITE, unlock, and apply to all enclosing....

after some time (applying to enclosing) restart... and the time machine backup will work :-)